# How to merge my client's log4j property file into my jar's one, sl4j?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Here is my case, I use `slfj` and provide a lib to my clients. And I have my logging rules, so that I can debug them into separate log file, say client.log, tools,log, which helps to diagnose:

```
log4j.logger.cn.webank=info,rmbAppender

log4j.appender.rmbAppender.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.rmbAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rmbAppender.File=${user.home}/logs/rmblogs/log4j/rmb-client.log
log4j.appender.rmbAppender.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.rmbAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rmbAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%p] [%t] [%l] - [%m]%n
```

I want :

1. I provide jar and the my log will logged as my rule but this will not affect my clients' logging.
2. If my client's log have conflic with mine, they will overide mine.

Now I use reflection to achive #1

```
    String logConfigFilePath = SOME_VALUE_FROM_EXTERNAL

    final String log4j_resource_file = "rmb-log4j.properties";

        //log4j
        if (classType.getName().equals("org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory")) {
            final Class<?> PropertyConfigurator ;
            final Object PropertyConfiguratorObj;
            PropertyConfigurator = Class.forName("org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator");
            PropertyConfiguratorObj = PropertyConfigurator.newInstance();
            if (null == logConfigFilePath) {
                Method configure = PropertyConfiguratorObj.getClass().getMethod("configure", URL.class);
                URL url = RMBLogger.class.getClassLoader().getResource(log4j_resource_file);
                configure.invoke(PropertyConfiguratorObj, url);
            } else {
                Method configure = PropertyConfiguratorObj.getClass().getMethod("configure", String.class);
                configure.invoke(PropertyConfiguratorObj, logConfigFilePath);
            }
        }
```

But as to #2, if my client have a property that hopes to overide the file path in their provided log4j property like:

```
log4j.appender.rmbAppender.File=${user.home}/logs/rmblogs/log4j/rmb-client-client-define.log
```

It does not work. I think this is because the client ones initize first and the my jar's one overide it, is there any way to overide my file path with my client's